# Linked lists, Manipulation difficulties

Tags: c, error-handling, linked-list

I am having difficulties manipulating a few things using linked lists,

First thing am having issues with, is for this section of my code where I am reading data from a file, and populating my nodes with it. However I keep getting a warning where I have indicated on the code, for comparing pointer type int to a int and incompatible pointer type respectively :

```
void readfile(node *curr, node *newlist, int *quanta, int *readincrement, int *newincrement, int *procnumb)
{
    int i;
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    fscanf(myFile,"%d",quanta);
    fscanf(myFile,"%d",newincrement);
    fscanf(myFile,"%d",readincrement);
    fscanf(myFile,"%d",procnumb);

    newlist = malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr = newlist;
    for(i=0;i<procnumb;i++)//pointer error
    {
        curr->process = 'A' + i;
        printf("%s",curr->process);
        curr->state = '-';
        printf("%s",curr->state);
        fscanf(myFile,"%d",&curr->NUT);
        printf("%d",curr->NUT);
        fscanf(myFile,"%d",&curr->AT);
        printf("%d", curr->AT);
        curr->Prio = '0';
        printf("%d",curr->Prio);
        curr->next = malloc(sizeof (node));
        curr->next = curr;//pointer error.
    }
}
```

Second issue am having is a function to move a node from the top of `newlist` to the bottom of `readylist`, I keep getting an error where indicated in the code and I have no idea why:

```
//move node from new list, to ready list.
void move(node *newlist, node *readylist)
{
    readylist->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    while(readylist->next != NULL)
    {
        if(readylist->next == newlist)
            readylist->next = readylist->next->next;//pointer error here.
        readylist = readylist->next;
    }

    readylist->next = newlist;
    newlist->next = NULL;
    return readylist;
}
```

In your answer I would appreciate a brief explanation to why they are occurring, I am really struggling with this subject at the moment and working hard to get to grips with it.

EDIT: Forgot to add the Struct section here it is:

```
struct record//too contain several data types.
{
    char process;
    char state;
    int  NUT;
    int  AT;
    int  Prio;

    struct reord *next;
};
typedef struct record node;

void move(node *newlist, node *readylist);

void readfile(node *reading,node *newlist, int *quanta, int *readincrement, int *newincrement, int *procnumb);

main()
{
    int quanta, readincrement, newincrement, procnumb;
    node *readylist = {NULL};//pointing at nothing.
    node *newlist = {NULL};
    node *curr = {NULL};
    node *next = {NULL};
    node *Rcurr = {NULL};
    node *Rnext = {NULL};
}
```

Comment: Well, 'i<procnumb' one is an int and the other an int*.  You cannot compare them.  That is what the compiler error message says.

Comment: OT may as well tell you now, `readfile` will do nothing regarding actually populating a linked list on the caller-side. It will populate those `int*` out parameters if you're fortunate to not experience any errors on the four-pack of `fscanf` calls, but after that, it is a memory-leak generator, as the caller has no way of receiving the list head. And you leak the open `FILE*` stream as well, assuming it actually opened.

Comment: @WhozCraig i didn't get any errors on the 4 fscans, and what do u mean the caller has no way of receiving the list head?

Comment: also i did test that function to read from a file and display it, without using linked lists in a different programme and it worked with no leaks, am only starting to get these issues when am dealing with this kind of prog.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said. The only out-parameters set in that code are the integer params. Both incoming original values for `curr` and `newList` are lost prior to the loop, so a "sentinel node" algorithm won't work. Not that any of that matters, because the allocation loop is also completely broken. `curr->next = malloc(sizeof (node)); curr->next = curr;` leaks memory, sets `curr->next` to point to `curr` (itself), repeatedly populates that single node with the next read data, which is ultimately lost anyway. In short, that function needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: And *"i didn't get any errors on the 4 fscans"* - *compiling*, maybe. but what about validating they *succeeded* at *run-time* ? Assumption is the mother of all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1:

Replace

`for(i=0;i<procnumb;i++)` \Here you are comparing an integer and a address pointing to integer

with

`for(i=0;i<*procnumb;i++)`\Now you are comparing an integer with a integer

Comment: thanks, ya i fixed a few things related to syntax since your comment :)